# .NET: Getting the absolute path for a file when running VS Team Test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Currently I have a test class called TestClass.cs in C:\Projects\TestProject\TestClass.cs

I also have an Xml file in C:\Projects\TestProject\config\config.xml

In TestClass.cs, I have a test method to load the Xml from the filesystem like so:

`XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "config\config.xml"));`

Unfortunately, the Location property gives me the value:
C:\Projects\TestProject\TestResults\klaw_[computernamehere] [time here]\

instead of what I want, which is C:\Projects\TestProject\

I've tried Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase as well with similar results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark this file with the DeploymentItemAttribute if you're using MSTest. This means it will be copied with the DLL.

Comment: I added the DeploymentItemAttribute and passed in the path of the xml file, and loaded it directly in the unit test without having to worry about paths. That worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a test, how about making the file an embedded resource? You can then read the embedded resource at runtime with the following code:

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
```

The resource is normally the namespace + filename. But you can work this out by running
the following code in the debugger:

```
AssemblyGetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

This returns a list of embedded resources.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is telling the truth. Unlike NUnit / TestDriven.NET, etc - MSTest copied things around into a different folder for each test. Which is (IMO) a pain - for example, you need to either attribute files to include ([`[DeploymentItem]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.deploymentitemattribute(VS.80).aspx)), or specify them in the testrunconfig (properties -> Deployment -> Add File...).

Contrast this to TestDriven.NET, where you could use the "Copy to Output Directory" flag.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to marking an item with [DeploymentItem], you will also need to make sure your test run configuration has Enable Deployment checked along with the directory of where to grab items from.